# Importing .hy file with function definition in .py file and after calling function from .hy from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hy

My `.py` file looks like:

```
import hy
import example
foo2()
```

My `.hy` file looks like:

```
(defn foo2 [] (+ 1 1))
```

`.hy` file is in same folder as `.py` file.

If I run `.py` file I am getting error:

```
runfile('D:/del/hy2/untitled46.py', wdir='D:/del/hy2')
Reloaded modules: example
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-274-3982ada2f243>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/del/hy2/untitled46.py', wdir='D:/del/hy2')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/del/hy2/untitled46.py", line 3, in <module>
    foo2()

NameError: name 'foo2' is not defined
```

**Question:** How to correct my code above if I want to call function defined in `.hy` file from `.py` file with Python?

---

By the way this works fine.

In `.py` file:

```
import hy
import example
```

In `.hy` file:

```
(print "Hello, World")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python can't resolve the name `foo2` in that context. Maybe you meant `from example import foo2`? I'm assuming your `.hy` file is the `example` module you imported.

Comment: `from example import foo2` solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Gilch! You're alive!